# Java Inverting Switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

So I have come across an interesting problem that I want to solve with an even more interesting method.
So I want to make a switch statement that works like this
*Inserting weird looking fake code:*

```
int i = 5;
switch (i)
case 0:
this line works
break;
case 1:
this line works
break;
case 2:
this line works
break;
case 3:
this line works
break;
case 4:
this line works
break;
case 5:
this line does not work
break;
case 6:
this line works
break;
```

Ignoring the obivious missing code(we all know what switch statement looks like (if you don't then hi I guess, welcome to this weird programming place)) and the main problem here is the question of implementing such case statement that works as shown above.
Edit: if you still don't understand my question, I want the case statement to output every other case but the one I selected.

Comment: Unknown line and unknown problem... Hard to tell

Comment: This is not a "I have an error in my code question" this is "how to do this" question. so there's no actual code involved really.

Comment: A switch cannot do that. Use a series of `if` statements instead,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `if`s:

```
int i = 5;
if (i != 0)
    // this line works
if (i != 1)
    // this line works
if (i != 2)
    // this line works
if (i != 3)
    // this line works
if (i != 4)
    // this line works
if (i != 5)
    // this line does not work
if (i != 6)
    // this line works
```

Answer (score 1):

Not possible, switch can only do one case. The thing you can do is add for loop if you really want switch

```
int i = 5;

for(n=0 ; n <= 6 ; n++){
if(n == i){
n++;
}

switch (n)
case 0:
this line works
break;
case 1:
this line works
break;
case 2:
this line works
break;
case 3:
this line works
break;
case 4:
this line works
break;
case 5:
this line does not work
break;
case 6:
this line works
break;

}
```

This will skip 5